# Resources for character and text processing (encoding, regular expressions, NLP)

Tags: parsing, text, encoding, text-processing, linguistics

I'd like to learn foundations of encodings, characters and text. Understanding these is important for dealing with a large set of text whether that are log files or text source for building algorithms for collective intelligence. My current knowledge is pretty basic: something like "As long as I use UTF-8, I'm okay."

I don't say I need to learn about advanced topics right away. But I need to know:

- Bit and bytes level knowledge of encodings.
- Characters and alphabets not used in English.
- Multi-byte encodings. (I understand some Chinese and Japanese. And parsing them is important.)
- Regular expressions.
- Algorithm for text processing.
- Parsing natural languages.

I also need an understanding of mathematics and corpus linguistics. The current and future web (semantic, intelligent, real-time web) needs processing, parsing and analyzing large text.

I'm looking for some resources (maybe books?) that get me started with some of the bullets. **(I find many helpful discussion on regular expressions here on Stack Overflow. So, you don't need to suggest resources on that topic.)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In addition to wikipedia, Joel Spolskys [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on **encoding** is really good too.
- This free [character map](http://www.atm.ox.ac.uk/user/iwi/charmap.html) is a nice resource for all unicode characters.
- This **regular expression** [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) can be helpful.
- Specifically on **NLP** and **Japanese**, you could
  take a look at this [Japanese NLP](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/japanesenlp/default.aspx)
  project.
- On **text processing**, [this](http://java-source.net/open-source/text-processing) Open
  Source project can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As is usual for most general "I want to learn about X topic" questions, Wikipedia is a good place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing